# How to create generic methods that take any type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have an abstract superservice that should perform some common logic. Several services implement this superservice. I chose the ServiceImpl based on a condition, and want to assign it to the abstract type, for later running the common logic.

What is wrong with the following? I'd like to pass into the `process()` method any object that is of / extends `BaseResponse`, like `FirstResponse` in my example.

```
//superservice
abstract class AbstractService<T extends BaseResponse> {
    public void process(T t) {
        //execute logic that is common to a BaseResponse
    }
}

//implementations
class FirstService extends AbstractService<FirstResponse extends BaseResponse> {
}

//usage
AbstractService<? extends BaseResponse> myservice = new FirstService(); //chose by condition
myservice.process(new FirstResponse()); //ERROR
```

result:

```
    The method build(capture#2-of ? extends BaseResponse) 
in the type AbstractService<capture#2-of ? extends BaseResponse> is not applicable for the arguments (FirstResponse)
```

Comment: Does `FirstService` work with a `BaseResponse`, or any subclass of `BaseResponse`, or a specific subclass?

Comment: I think `AbstractService<? super BaseResponse> myservice = new FirstService()` should do the trick isn't so?

Comment: `FirstService` will work with the `BaseResponse`; `? super` will make it possible to call `myservice.process()`, but I then cannot assign `FirstService` anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    //execute logic that is common to a BaseResponse
```

If that's the case, the flexibility provided by inheritance is enough, you don't really need generics.

```
public void process(BaseResponse t) {
    // ...
}
```

---

The reason of error is that, the Java compiler only knows `myservice` is an `AbstractService<? extends BaseResponse>`. It is not wrong to reassign `myservice` to a different subclass later:

```
AbstractService<? extends BaseResponse> myservice = new FirstService();
myservice = new SecondService(); // <---------- should be ok
myservice.process(new FirstResponse()); // <--- making this bad
```

would probably be a true error. If you need to keep the interface of `process(T)`, you have to change the type of `myservice` then:

```
FirstService myservice = new FirstService();
myservice.process(new FirstResponse());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with generics like this:

```
abstract class AbstractService<T extends BaseResponse> {
    public void process(T t) {
        //execute logic that is common to a BaseResponse
    }
}

//implementations
class FirstService extends AbstractService<FirstResponse> {
    @Override
    public void process(FirstResponse firstResponse) {
        super.process(firstResponse);
        ...
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //usage
    AbstractService<FirstResponse> myservice = new FirstService(); 
    myservice.process(new FirstResponse()); 
}
```

Comment: But with this I for example could not write: `AbstractService<FirstResponse> myservice = new SecondService();` if `class SecondService<SecondResponse>`. I'd like to chose the service based on a condition, and then run `myservice.process` whatever the service is.

Comment: An unchecked cast is an easy way I can think of `AbstractService<BaseResponse> myservice = (AbstractService) new FirstService();`, discouraged however.